# Почему при движении 2d персонажа через rb.velocity не используется Time.fixedDeltaTime?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему при движении 2d персонажа через rb.velocity не используется Time.fixedDeltaTime? Я много раз видел, что при движении шарика вокруг какого-нибудь объекта с применением функции RotateAround() используют умножение на Time.fixedDeltaTime. Так почему, когда задают движение персонажу используют такой код:

```
float moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
```

Comment: Теперь это дубликат более обширного вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Time.DeltaTime` это, фактически, время между прорисовкой 2х кадров. На каждой прорисовке кадра вызывается `Update()`.

`Time.FixedDeltaTime` это, фактически, время между двух вызовов `FixedUpdate()`.

Соответственно, если ты хочешь получить статическое передвижение обьекта без скачков или проседаний во время проседания количества кадров, ты должен использовать `Time.DeltaTime` в `Update()` или `Time.FixedDeltaTime` в `FixedUpdate()`.

Это уравновешивает проседание кадров и скорость обьекта и обьект будет двигатся с равномерной скоростью.

`rb.Velocity` - это **физическая** скорость обьекта. Скорость обьекта с учетом физики и времени. То есть она может изменятся во времени сама под действием неких физических законов. Например, мы задумали сделать скачек персонажа:

```
if (IsGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
    Debug.Log("jump");
}
```

мы разово задаем вектор скачка. Но он будет изменятся во времени автоматически равномерно уменьшаясь под силой тяжения. Пока не станет нулевым (верхняя точка прыжка), а потом не пойдет в минус по Y (падение).

`RotateAround()` это уже не физическая характеристика. Мы меняем просто позицию и поворот с учетом промежутка времени между прорисовкой(что  бы обьект не скакал).

Если же мы в какой-то момент перестанем задавать скорость `RotateAround()` - обьект просто остановится. Ибо это не буквально скорость **в физическом смысле** , а просто изменение позиции обьекта относительно другого обьекта.

Точто так же как перемещение при помощи изменения `transform.position` -- это НЕ работа с физикой. Это **телепортация** обьекта *(из-за чего у новичков часто бывают проблемы с дерганьем персонажа близ какого-то коллайдера или прохождению сквозь коллайдер в отдельных случаях)* . Такое движение не будет физическим действием. И как только мы перестанем обьект так двигать -- обьект просто остановится а не продолжит движение с затуханием, как если бы мы использовали физическое ускорение.

Comment: `FixedUpdate` - это вызов итерации расчета физики, задается через настройки и может не совпадать с частотой кадров. Так если вы зададите в настройках 5мс, а на отрисовку кадра уходит 15мс, то в промежутках между кадрами физика должна пересчитаться трижды. Но следует еще принимать во внимание что частота с которой считает процессор может не совпадать с заданной, и физика в таком случае считается скажем каждые 10мс. В итоге у вас на одном кадре может быть последовательно запущено от 2 до 4 итераций просчета физики. Для этого и существует два разных времени.

Comment: А еще управлять объектами с физикой лучше через `RigidBody`. Потому, что каждое задание через `Transform` позиции или поворота(в т.ч. и  `RotateAround()`) равноценно телепортации объекта в новое место и это может сводить движок физики с ума). Чаще всего отсюда и вылазят проблемы с проваливанием объектов через пол, пролетанием пуль через стены и т.п.