# Персонаж проходит сквозь стену (Коллайдеры стоят)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сразу:

1. Коллайдеры стоят на всём;
2. RigidBody стоит только на мне;

Изначально использовал метод перемещения такой :прибавлял к *.position transform.forward/right. Но сейчас возникла проблема, иногда при "столкновении" с объектом я прохожу через стену. Главное предположение - тонкий коллайдер, т.е. у меня прибавление к позиции гораздо больше толщины, но возникает проблема другая, что нужно сделать, чтобы не возникала такая проблема. Вектор изменить не могу, т.к. скорость измениться, а толщину Коллайдера тоже, так как придётся переделывать некоторые модельки. Пробовал через AddForce, но мешает ускорение, так же пытался использовать *.velocity, но не могу одновременно идти, например, прямо и вправо.

Можете посоветовать другие способы передвижения(AWSD)?

Comment: Здесь есть обьяснение как это делать правильно и почему: [Почему при движении 2d персонажа через rb.velocity не используется Time.fixedDeltaTime?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929547/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-2d-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-rb-velocity-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-time-fixeddel)

Comment: Более детальная информация по вопросу здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
}
```

Код взят с официальной документации по юнити: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-player

Формально значения берутся со стрелочек или с штурвальчика на геймпаде и возможно с WASD -- но не уверен, а проверять влом. ( Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"); ) от такого кода не будет постоянного ускорения как видно из официального видеопримера.

Изменение параметров указанных в ответе **Stranger in the Q** приведет к лишним затратам ресурсов. Это делать нежелательно. Но допустимо если движение изначально реализованы по-человечески, а не через "телепортацию", как в даном случае.

> пытался использовать *.velocity, но не могу одновременно идти, например, прямо и вправо.

Через Volocity так же можно сделать движение и в том числе диагональное, как того хочется.

Уверяю, в интернете можно найти примеры. Вот код из головы который поддерживает бег по диагонали, который можно попробовать довести до толка:

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(0,0,0);

if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) 
{ 
 movement = new Vector3(movement.x,movement.y,1.0f * Speed);
}
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) 
{ 
 movement = new Vector3(movement.x,movement.y, - 1.0f * Speed);
} 
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) 
{ 
 movement = new Vector3(-1.0f * Speed,movement.y,movement.z);
}
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) 
{ 
 movement = new Vector3(1.0f * Speed,movement.y,movement.z);
}

player.velocity = movement;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Похоже то, что мне нужно, немножко поправить, чтобы учитывал поворот головы(думаю здесь мне хватит моих знаний в АнГеоме и ЛинАнале), а так идеально, пойду дальше разбираться.

Comment: более детально расписал здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4

Answer (score 0):

Осмелюсь предположить что вы наткнулись на проблему связанную с тем, что ваш код выполняется в методе в рамках генерации кадра, а физика просчитывается в другие моменты времени, попробуйте переключить вот эти параметры (отметил красным)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: плохо прочитал вопрос. То, что изменение колижн детекта помогло каким-то чудом не значит что это правильное решение :) У него движение реализовано через изменение `transform.position`. Правильным решением было бы посоветовать зайти на оф.документацию по юнити и подсмотреть как правильно реализовать передвижение обьекта через velocity :)

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, просто не заметил, что поставил галочку на ответе. Вообщем я решил забросить идею через position и попробовал velocity, передвижение достаточно гладко и не происходит проблем с столкновением, но есть другая проблема, я не могу одновременно использовать несколько направлений, например, W и A(Тут понятно почему, так как я ставлю значения Вектора , который передаю затем в *.velocity, но как исправить - нз). Да я бы не пришёл сюда, если бы не прочитал там, но чот как-то хорошую реализацию не нашёл, в большинстве случаев используется Ввод с джойстиков(если я правильно понял)

Comment: Вот пример для одного направления:

if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
   //player.position = player.position + body.transform.forward * willpower;
   player.velocity = new Vector3(player.transform.forward.x*50,player.velocity.y, player.transform.forward.z*50)*willpower;
  }

Comment: @Михаил почитай мой ответ